# Exit status of a piped command executed over ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I'm executing a piped command chain in bash via ssh. I want to exit if any one of the command fails. Its okay if the the exit happens after the whole pipelines finishes executing. I just want to assign the pipeline an overall 'fail' status  if one of the command fails.

A minimal example is:

`ssh $REMOTE_HOST "CMD1 | CMD2" >> file.txt`

I want to exit with failure if any one command in the pipeline fails. If I'm executing the command chain locally, I can use `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` to pluck out exit status of any command in a chain. But over ssh, I'm getting the exit status of the last command. I.e. if `CMD1` fails and `CMD2` succeeds, `$?` on localhost gives me `0`. How can I assign an overall fail status to the pipeline if `CMD1` fails?

Comment: Nothing about "over ssh" is an essential part of the question -- you could take out the SSH and still have the same problem. Consider doing that as part of finding the core of your issue before asking next time.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy As my questions states, I was able to run `PIPESTATUS` to pluck out exit status of any command in the chain when running locally. As I recall, I was unable to use `PIPESTATUS` to run over `ssh` and get 'overall' exit status. Hence that extra bit of specification.

Comment: `PIPESTATUS` isn't transmitted to the local shell, but you can run it on the remote end. That is: `ssh "$host" bash <<<'CMD | CMD2; exit $((PIPESTATUS[0] | ${PIPESTATUS[1]}))'`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I understand that. But that would complicate my command.  For example I might have to use something like `STATUS=$(ssh "cmd1 | cmd2; PIPESTATUS[*]")` followed by `if [ STATUS -ne 0 ] ...`

Comment: I do understand, now, why specifying SSH made sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this question is tagged `bash`, I assume the default shell of your remote user is Bash. In that case, you should set [the `pipefail` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin) through `set -o pipefail`. According to Bash Reference Manual linked above:

> If set, the return value of a pipeline is the value of the last (rightmost) command to exit with a non-zero status, or zero if all commands in the pipeline exit successfully. This option is disabled by default.

Try, for instance,

```
ssh $REMOTE_HOST 'false | true'
ssh $REMOTE_HOST 'set -o pipefail; false | true'
```

to see the difference in exit status of the `ssh` command.

---

On the other hand, if your remote user's default shell is `zsh`, like I do, you should use `setopt pipe_fail` instead. Be aware this is a relatively recent addition to zsh. I can't say for sure when it was added, but I know it works on 5.0.5 but not 5.0.2.

Comment: I think previously I misread the first line of the question as you are executing the `ssh` command in bash, from which I cannot infer your remote shell. Sorry about that. Anyway, I believe there's nothing wrong with providing additional info about `zsh`.

Comment: My shell is bash locally and bash remote. The `set -o pipefail` does exactly what I had in mind.